# how to show the list of filenames in listview from SDcard in android?

Tags: android

```
file  =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
```

Using this I am getting total path with file names

**ex:/storage/sdcard/filename1
/storage/sdcard/filename2**

My question is how to get the filename without total path?

Answer (score 0):

use `getName()` method to get the name from the path

```
String name = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Images/ImageName").getName();
```